# To calculate the final velocity, (v) of a moving body that had an initial velocity, (u)...

Tags: integration

...and had been under constant acceleration, $a$ for a period of time, $t$ the following formula is used:

**$$v = u + at$$**

so the following terms are constant,initial vel.$u$ and the constant acceleration, $a$.

Given the definition of velocity is the rate of change distance in a constant direction and assuming the body is moving in a straight line.

i.e. **$$v = \frac{ds}{dt}$$** where $s$ is distance travelled

Integrate $v$ with respect to time $t$ to find the formula for calculating the distance $s$ travelled in a time $t$

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask here?

Comment: You just have to integrate the function $v(t) = u + a t$ if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

$$s=\int v\ dt=\int(u+at)\ dt=ut+\frac12at^2$$

Recognise this?

Comment: Thank your got it!